# how is it possible to store an integer in a character variable?

Tags: c

How can char variable data2 in the program below store an integer value?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
   int data1 = 1230;             //initialize data1 with 1230
   char data2 = data1;           //initialize data2 variable with data1 variable
   printf("data2 = %X\n",data2);         // print data2 variable
   printf("data1 = %X\n",data1);         // print data1 variable
   printf("data2 size = %d\n",sizeof(data2)); //print size of data2 variable
   return 0;
}

 answer:
data2 = FFFFFFCE
data1 = FFFFFFCE
data2 size = 1
```

Comment: They are both numbers in memory char just tends to be shorter than int.

Comment: just execute the program and see the answer first

Comment: CHAR_MIN 
minimum value of char 
(macro constant)
CHAR_MAX 
maximum value of char, usually char is minimum size of addressable memory due to optimization therefore it may be bigger than expected

Comment: In this case, it is not possible at all. You should get a warning about a possible loss of precision. `data2` will turn out to be something different than `1230`, as `char` cannot hold such large numbers.

Comment: @rageshmr, While posting at SO it is good practice to make sure that your post contain the output of your relevant buggy program. It helps other users to draw inference quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ce 04 00 00 -> data1 = 1230 it is data1's memory struct
```

data2 = data1 in assembly it is

```
001C13A5  mov         al,byte ptr [data1]  
001C13A8  mov         byte ptr [data2],al
```

so the value of data2 is `ce`, that is what we expet.
but why we saw `FFFFFFCE` on our screen ? i think it is because of `printf`

Answer (score 3):

You *can* use a `char` to store an integral value but be *very* careful:

For starters, the range of values that can be stored in a `char` is platform dependent although the C standard mandates it to be one byte (i.e. 8 bits); *i.e.* `sizeof(char)` is 1.  Some platforms define it to be   a `signed char` which has a range -128 to +127. Others define it as an `unsigned char` which has a range 0 to +255. The C standard permits implementations to pick the one most appropriate to the machine architecture.

To get round this, always use `signed char` and `unsigned char` explicitly.

Note that to coerce any number outside the range to a `char`, a `signed char` or an `unsigned char` is *undefined behaviour*.

(Not strictly relevant but worth pointing out: In Java, a `char` is a 16 bit unsigned type. It has a range 0 to +65535.)

Answer (score 1):

In C, `char` is an integral type, it can store integer values within its range. In your code, the value of `data1` is cast to a `char`, and then stored in `data2`.

You can even use `char` variables in arithmetic:

```
char a = 'A';
int n = a + 100;
printf("%d\n", n);
```

Comment: why compiler showing warning when i using char data = 257

Comment: @rageshmr It overflows, remember that `char` has only one byte. Also note that whether `char` is signed or unsigned is implementation-defined.

Comment: @rageshmr Ask yourself how big a char is on your platform, and which range of values you can store in a char.

Answer (score 0):

`char` data type is just like `int` in `C`. It has only **one byte** storage space, so it can represent a integers within `-128 to +127`. Now, most of the times you have seen `unsigned char` which is used to increase the range of integers up to `255`. Have a look at the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char data;

    data = 127; // here within the limit -128 to +127
    printf("%d\n",data);

    data = 140;  // something greater  than 127
    printf("%d",data); // here it overflows
}
```

**Output :**

```
127
-116
```

But if you use `unsigned char` :

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    unsigned char data;

    data = 127; // here within the limit 0 to 255
    printf("%d\n",data);

    data = 140;  // something greater  than 127
    printf("%d",data); // now it does not overflows
}
```

**Output:**

```
127
140
```

How to get range of char on your platform. It's easy :

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>
...

printf("range of signed character is %i ... %i", CHAR_MIN, CHAR_MAX );
```

**NOTE:**

A `character` is what represents the elementary block of storage i.e `1 Byte` and it is not necessary that `1 Byte = 8 bits` but it is so on most implementations. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte for more information.